# неверная отправка .txt файла TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

почему, когда я отправляю текст из *txt* файла, он отправляется неправильно. Для теста я взял файл, в котором было 5029 строк текста такого формата:

`blablalba:blabla:Hello my friends`,

однако на сервер пришло 5036 строк +-1.
Вот код сервера:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter outformat = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Accounts.txt", FileMode.Append))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            // Получаем кол-во строк передаваемого файла
            int line = int.Parse(outformat.Deserialize(stream).ToString());

            // Получаем размер файла
            int count = int.Parse(outformat.Deserialize(stream).ToString());

            // Записываем по 1024 байта
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 1024)
            {
                byte[] buf = (byte[])(outformat.Deserialize(stream));
                bw.Write(buf);
            }

            Logger.WarninMessage = "Recv [" + DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + "][" + ipClientConnected + "]: " + line;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код клиента:

```
using (client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(address, port);

    BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();

    using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        // Отправляем кол-во строк в файле
        int line = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Length;
        format.Serialize(stream, line.ToString());

        // Отравка файла
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file);

            // Отправляем размер файла
            format.Serialize(stream, file.Length.ToString());

            while ((reader.Read(buf, 0, 1024)) > 0)
            {
                format.Serialize(stream, buf);
            }
        }
                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы на сервере всегда "дописываете" файл блоками по 1024 байта. В то же время, размер файла может быть не кратен 1024. Мне кажется, для "последнего блока" нужно сделать исключение. Проще всего - потренироваться на маленьком файле, размером 1-2 строки

Comment: @S.H. да, спасибо, на самом деле я уже разобрался) но спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перемудрили. `BinaryFormatter` устарел и не является безопасным, его нельзя использовать для передачи данных по сети. К тому же проще передавать все файлы как двоичные.

Вот вам 2 метода

```cs
private static void SendFile(string path, Stream stream)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
    if (!file.Exists)
    {
        // файл не найден
        throw new IOException("File not found: " + path);
    }
    long length = file.Length; // длина файла в байтах
    string name = file.Name; // имя файла
    Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false); // UTF-8 без BOM, самый стандартный стандарт из всех стандартов
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream, utf8, true))
    {
        bw.Write(length);
        bw.Write(name);
    }
    using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead())
    {
        fs.CopyTo(stream);
    }
}

private static void ReceiveFile(string directory, Stream stream)
{
    Directory.Create(directory); // создает каталог, если он не существует
    Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(false);
    long length;
    string name;
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream, utf8, true))
    {
        length = br.ReadInt64();
        name = br.ReadString();
    }
    // Path.GetFileName для безопасности. Вдруг кто-то пришлет серверу полный путь,
    // чтобы он записал что-то в папку Windows или повредил свои файлы. Этого нельзя допустить.
    string path = Path.Combine(directory, Path.GetFileName(name));
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        long received = 0;
        while (received < length)
        {
            int toReceive = (int)Math.Min(buffer.Length, length - received);
            int bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer, 0, toReceive);
            if (bytesReceived == 0) // Неожиданный конец потока
                throw new IOException("Unexpected end of stream while receiving file: " + path);
            received += bytesReceived;
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда ваш код из вопроса будет выглядеть так

```cs
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(address, port);
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        try
        {
            SendFile("file.txt", stream);
            // здесь файл успешно отправлен
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // произошла ошибка при отправке (ex.Message)
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    try
    {
        ReceiveFile("ReceivedFiles", stream); // указываем каталог, куда записать полученный файл
        // здесь файл успешно получен
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // произошла ошибка при получении (ex.Message)
    }
}
```

При этом отправлять и принимать можно с любой стороны. Имя сохраняемого на диск файла задается отправляющим.

Смысла различать текстовые файлы и двоичные нет никакого, конечно до тех пор, пока вы не захотите текстовые файлы упаковывать при передаче для экономии трафика (см. `GZipStream`). Но я не рекомендую вам этим заниматься, пока вы не настроите полностью и не отладите свой протокол передачи данных.

Comment: Какой раз вы меня выручаете, спасибо большое) сделал немного проще, но отрабатывает на ура. Правда используется `BinaryFormatter`, но я понял что его уже использовать не целесообразно.

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV проще, чем я вам показал - это только выкинуть контроль ошибок, ну или багов понаписать. Где это я так переусложнил, что вы были вынуждены упростить? Форматтер выкидывайте, он здесь вообще ни к чему. Я правда не знаю, как это проще написать.

Comment: `outformat.Deserialize(stream).ToString()` так просто из стрима выводил текстовое сообщение и все, не заморачивался тем, что перекидывал по частям

Comment: @GRAMOTEY `name = br.ReadString();` - точно сложнее, чем это? Это ж по сути прием и передача строки.

Comment: по сути да) спасибо

Comment: у меня еще вопрос, как я могу указать для слушателя принимать определенные IP адресса на подключение? Циклом? Или как? Сейчас просто стоит Any

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV если вы имеете в виду с каких удаленных адресов принимать подключение, то никак. В параметрах вы можете задать только IP адрес интерфейса, на котором выполняется прослушивание. Что касается удаленных адресов, для этого требуется фаервол. Ну либо в качестве костыля, принимаете подключение, проверяете Remote EndPoint, и если удаленный IP надо отключить, закрываете соединение.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, на самом деле печально конечно

Comment: а эта реализация подойдет для отправки файлов более 1Гб?

Comment: @Podreju до 9 223 372 036 854 775 807 байт. Есть догадки, почему?

Comment: простите за глупый вопрос, понял