# Передача файлов по TCP C#

Tags: c#, tcp

На C# хочу передать файл по TCP. В гугле есть куча примеров, но они все в подобных этому вопросах, ответом в которых является совет: "Передавайте сначала длинну, а потом уже сам файл". Подскажите, пожалуйста, а лучше пример, как передавать файлы по TCP. Достаточно по локальной сети. Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648960/10105

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253115/373567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот вам простейший клиент и сервер на C# 9, без проверки на ошибки и с захардкодированными параметрами. При подсоединении клиента сервер тут же шлёт ему предзаданный файл, а клиент принимает файл и записывает его на диск.

Сервер:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;
const int localPort = 7777;
const string filename = "test.txt";

var server = new TcpListener(localAddress, localPort);
server.Start();

while (true)
{
    var client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    _ = Task.Run(() => Serve(client, filename));
}

static async Task Serve(TcpClient client, string filename)
{
    using var _ = client;
    var stream = client.GetStream();
    using var file = File.OpenRead(filename);
    var length = file.Length;
    byte[] lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(length));
    await stream.WriteAsync(lengthBytes);
    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

Клиент:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

IPAddress serverAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;
const int serverPort = 7777;
string filename = "test.txt";

using var client = new TcpClient(serverAddress.ToString(), serverPort);
var stream = client.GetStream();

byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
await ReadBytes(sizeof(long));
long remainingLength = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt64(buf, 0));

using var file = File.Create(filename);
while (remainingLength > 0)
{
    int lengthToRead = (int)Math.Min(remainingLength, buf.Length);
    await ReadBytes(lengthToRead);
    await file.WriteAsync(buf, 0, lengthToRead);
    remainingLength -= lengthToRead;
}

async Task ReadBytes(int howmuch)
{
    int readPos = 0;
    while (readPos < howmuch)
    {
        var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, readPos, howmuch - readPos);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        readPos += actuallyRead;
    }
}
```

Что клиент, что сервер настолько просты, что даже классы не нужны.

Если будете использовать сервер между хостами, не забудьте открыть порт при помощи

```
netsh http add urlacl http://+:7777/ user=%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%
```

в админской консоли.

Comment: Я сразу увидел ваш ответ, пока проверял, вы тут написали) Спасибо большое, действительно работает, хочу отметить, что в конце основного пакета данных, почему-то приклеиваются 2 символа "??". Читаю массив по длинне-2 символа. Ещё раз благодарю!

Comment: @ТаксистМолодой: Не за что! Странно, у меня проблема не воспроизводится, размер читаемого файла равен размеру записываемого, и контент совпадает. А какого размера ваш пересылаемый файл?

Comment: Тестирую на маленьких файликах 9-50байт. Файлики упаковываю в класс NetFile, как в предыдущем посте, и сериализую в Json. Возможно дело в этом?

Comment: А как вы определяете размер JSON? Попробуйте мой код без изменений — работает передача длины или нет?

Comment: JSON же это строка, а строка легко в массив байтов превращается. Пытался запустить, пишет вот: "System.IO.EndOfStreamException" - "Попытка чтения после конца потока."

Comment: @ТаксистМолодой: Ну, относительно легко. А покажите, как именно вы превращаете.

Comment: NetFile file = new NetFile();
                    file.FileName = Path.GetFileName(stream.Name);
                    file.Data = data;
                    String ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file);
                    byte[] to = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("05" + ser);
                    SendFileWithLengthPrefix(to, clientStream);

Comment: @ТаксистМолодой: Пока всё в порядке, а как выглядит `SendFileWithLengthPrefix` у вас? Может, вы шлёте `long`, а ожидаете при получении `int`?