# C# Не полностью передается массив байтов по сокету TCP

Tags: c#, unity3d, сокет, tcp

я делаю клиент-сервер игру на Unity , и у меня есть функционал по загрузке фото , на сервер . И при передаче фото на сервер ,  передается не то количество байтов.
Есть ли другой способ пересылать , большие изображения по tcp ?

Код отправителя (byte[] bytes это массив байтов картинки) , в конце выполнения пересылки картинки , я отправляю массив из 3 байтов end , чтобы сообщить что все было переслано.

```
        public void SendBytes(byte[] bytes, TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            using (var fs = new MemoryStream())
            {

                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                NetworkStream networkSteam = tcpClient.GetStream();


                const int BUFSIZE = 4096;
                int transferred = 0;
                long length = fs.Length;
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    while (transferred < length)
                    {
                        int chunkSize = Math.Min((int)length - transferred, BUFSIZE);
                        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(chunkSize);
                        networkSteam.Write(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
                        transferred += chunkSize;
                        Console.WriteLine("transferred  " + transferred);
                    }
                }
          
                var headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("end");
                networkSteam.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);

            }
        }
```

Код получатель, если пришло 3 байта то есть 'end' значит пересылка закончилась

```
     NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[4096];
        int byte_count;
        while ((byte_count = ns.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("byte_count " + byte_count);
            if (byte_count == 3)
            {
                _byteCount = 1;
                _receivedBytes = _bytes.ToArray();
                _bytes.Clear();
                IsSendingImage = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _bytes.AddRange(receivedBytes);
            }
        }
```

Вот пример как отправлено (Прошу прощения за качество)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как приходит(Консоль юнити)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP не гарантирует, что пакет не будет фрагментирован. TCP гарантирует только порядок получения пакетов и то что они будут доставлены (если это технически возможно в данный момент).

Другими словами, в наблюдаемой картине нет ничего странного. Просто оно вот так работает, это нормально.

То есть привязываться к тому что получаемые порции данных будут равны отправляемым - это ошибка. Вот [пример без ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253115/373567) - отправляете размер пакета, а следом данные.

Передача:

- отправляем размер пакета, к примеру 4 байта
- отправляем данные любыми порциями

Прием:

- ждем 4 байта, принимаем как число N
- принимаем ровно N байт любыми порциями
- ждем следующие 4 байта...

Вот так будет работать.

Если вы хотите реализовать свой TCP сервер и свой протокол, то [вот пример сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567) и правильной реализации протокола уровня приложения HTTP на базе TCP. Кстати, если это игра по сети, то для игровых пакетов лучше использовать UDP, а не TCP. TCP больше действительно подходит для передачи файлов, чем для маленьких частых игровых пакетов.