# Почему TCP Socket при получении ответа на запрос читает только первую букву?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

```
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = new (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.130"), 80));
            client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

            byte[] response = new byte[512];
            string responseMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, client.Receive(response));
            MessageBox.Show(responseMessage);

            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1384651/373567 Потому что нет гарантии, что при чтении сокета вы получите сразу весь пакет, так как он может быть фрагментирован как угодно. Вам нужно повторять получение до тех пор, пока количество байт не будет равно длине пакета, а чтобы узнать длину пакета, ее нужно тоже передавать, как заголовок к этому пакету. Получаете длину, например ровно 4 байта, а далее читаете сокет пока не получите указанное в длине количество байт. Никаким другим образом данная проблема не решается.

Comment: вот еще пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253115/373567 дополнительно почитайте про IDisposable объекты и как с ними работать. При работе с сокетами это очень важно.